# Google sheets app script pass values as range or individual cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a custom function which processes strings held in cells on a sheet.  How can I access the strings from within the function in a common way even if the function is given a range or a list of cells or a combination?

e.g. calling the function `myFunction(A1:B2)` or `myFunction(A1,A2,B1,B2)` or even `myFunction(A1:A2,B1,B2)` etc.

Do I need to determine inside the function how it has been called and combine all the different cell/range contents or is there a Google sheets api that can resolve all possible calls into a single range?

Thanks

Comment: I would break up each range to individual cells and then iterate through each cell as a rangelist

Comment: [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```
function myFunction(...args){
  const input = args.flat(2);
  //do stuff with input
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful in addressing the variable number of arguments function but still gives me strange results when there are a mix of individual cells and ranges given as arguments.

Comment: @JimBurke Maybe you could pin point the specifics of the strangeness(in a another question, if it isn't suitable for comments)?